# From a high-level, how do I allow non-logged in users to do certain things in my app - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As a non-logged in user, you can see one specific action of a model.

E.g. see: http://compversions.com/stages/40/compare?ck=o3NJC18Kj0LPe-vOpBfw&sk=rZFmkaDkN2U7cCx_69OT

However, if you try to add any comments or vote up or down any of the image, it doesn't allow you to do so.

How would I approach this ?

I know the simple answer is just to add an `before_filter :except => :create` on my `Comments` controller, but is that the only way ? That seems like using a sledgehammer to kill an ant. That would allow any non-logged in user to leave any comment (and access other comments) throughout my app, no ?

How do I restrict it to this one model (`stage`) and action (`compare`)?

Thanks.

P.S. I am using devise & decl_auth for authentication and authorization respectively.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent these UI elements from showing up at all for non-logged-in users, or do you want them to be present but nonfunctional (e.g. prompt the user to sign in, etc.)?

Comment: No...basically the way the system works is a designer uploads those images that you see on that link. Then they 'send it to a client'. Which essentially generates this public link and emails it to the client in one step. What I want to do is to allow that one client (i.e. anyone who has that URL) to be able to vote up or down on those images and then also to leave comments (we can also assume that the client is the one that left the comment, so I would just do something like set the name/author of the comment to `client.f_name`). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe look into [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Comment: Say you create and save the token as an image attribute, which is part of the URL in the mail. When the client clicks the URL, your ImagesController shows the image and embeds params[:token] as a hidden field for the comment form (in addition to the image_id). In CommentsController#create, you do Image.find(params[:image_id]) and make sure that @image.token matches params[:token] before allowing the comment to be saved. (I'm clear on how your Stage model associates to the Image or Comment models...)

Comment: Ahh.....interesting...ok that makes sense monocle. I think that gives me a nice first step, still need to parse it out some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a designer upload and image, then when that image is saved, you can generate a token and associate that to the image. Then when you send the email, add the token to the URL in the email as a query parameter. When the client clicks the link, you can capture the token parameter and only allow comments if that token is a match.

Comment: But how do I do that in context of different models ? E.g. the `comments` model is different than the `stages` model - which is where the client has access to.